# How to get response with SOAPAction in WCF 4.0 Service method?

Tags: wcf, service

I have a web service method which can return below response without (SOAPAction: "")

Method

```
public string SyncData(Stream xml)
{

}
```

**web.config**

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="" name="PRO.API">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="customBinding"
     bindingConfiguration="RawReceiveCapable" contract="PRO.IAPI" />
</service>
```

**customBinding**

```
<customBinding>    
<binding name="RawReceiveCapable">
<webMessageEncoding webContentTypeMapperType="PRO.RawContentTypeMapper, PRO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
<httpTransport manualAddressing="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288000" transferMode="Streamed" />
</binding>
</customBinding>

public class RawContentTypeMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
{
    public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
    {

        if (contentType.Contains("text/xml")
            || contentType.Contains("application/xml")
            || contentType.Contains("text/html"))
        {

            return WebContentFormat.Raw;

        }

        else
        {

            return WebContentFormat.Default;

        }
    }
}
```

**Required Response with SOAPAction: ""**

Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 346
**SOAPAction**: ""

```
<soapenv:Envelope" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<syncOrderRelationResponse xmlns="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/data/sync/v1_0/local">
<result>0</result>
<resultDescription>success</resultDescription>
</syncOrderRelationResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What should I do to get response with SOAPAction, thanks in adavnce?

please see this link for "Sample SOAP response"
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/wbsvcdg/62759/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1wblekhip1yrln1fv2s5b6a2d9f.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify Action property in OperationContract attribute. Check this question [How to specify custom SoapAction for WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192588/how-to-specify-custom-soapaction-for-wcf)

Comment: I need SOAPAction: "" in response not at the method calling

Comment: I solved the problem, actually it is very simple, just add any extra parameter in your response header 
    public string SyncData(Stream xml)
    {
     this.Context.Response.AddHeader("SOAPAction","\"\"");   
      
     return "OK";
    }

Comment: more better approched would be use convert stream to xml and take your desired action and make your response as requested,
    SOAPAction is added due to client request, 
    Note: SOAPAction parameter in Message header not in SOAP header

Comment: public XElement SyncData(Stream xml)
    {
    
    try
 {

Comment: WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"\""); 
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentLength = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(response);

Comment: }
 catch (Exception exp)
     {

 }
     return XElement.Parse(response);
    }