# wcf action url dynamically?

Tags: .net, wcf

My webservice shows the action url as

http://tempuri.org/Iservice/getPing

I see many posts like below telling me that I can redefine the url in the contract class

[How to specify custom SoapAction for WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192588/how-to-specify-custom-soapaction-for-wcf)

But I dont want to hardcode a fix url. I want my action url should be dynamic. If I am running my service on my staging url should be staging.com/Iservice/getPing and on productions  production.com/Iservice/getPing.  Is it possible? 
actually another question, I would like to ask before this, Is it also necessary ? In old asmx webservices, It was taken care of automatically, I guess.

thank you.

Comment: It's not service URL but _"...name and namespace of the contract in the WSDL <portType> element..."_ so you may simply ignore it (or, better, set to something meaningful). See also [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempuri). Don't forget it **must not change** otherwise your clients will see two different services.

Comment: @Adriano It is really good explanation. I thought that it is equal to what we had in asmx webservices. My action url in asmx looks like this staging.com/service.asmx?op=getPing. So you say that it is not the same? Am I confused things here? thank you.

Comment: That may be URL you use to invoke getPing method. That's fine, I guess. It'll change according to where your service has been published. It's not (and it shouldn't be) hardcoded anywhere. Imagine namespace as...namespace of your C# classes. It's part of contract then it shouldn't change (as it doesn't change for C# classes when you move an assembly from one directory to the other). It should be somehow unique for your web service but it's recommended, not strictly mandatory.

Comment: @Adriano thank you. I was confused just as it is a url. so it doesnt even have to be an http url. just anyname for namespace. Please write your answer as an answer and I can accept as answer. thank you.

Comment: No, it has do be a URL but it's recommended it is a valid URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not service URL (...*locator*) but "*...name and namespace of the contract in the WSDL  element...*" and it has to be a valid URI (...*identifier*) so you may simply ignore it (or, better, set to something meaningful). See also [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier).

Don't forget it [namespace] must not change otherwise your clients will see two different services. [Service] URL will change according to where your service has been published. It's not (and it shouldn't be) hardcoded anywhere.

Imagine URI namespace as...namespace of your C# classes. It's part of contract then it shouldn't change (as it doesn't change for C# classes when you move an assembly from one directory to the other). It should be somehow unique for your web service but it's recommended, not strictly mandatory.